# ECSlidingViewController shouldAllowUserInteractionsWhenAnchored is removed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ecslidingviewcontroller

I want to display same transition in `ECSlidingViewController` which is current git repository is not allow to slide as  `shouldAllowUserInteractionsWhenAnchored` like transition and i want to display same transition which is previous library display

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)addTopViewSnapshot
{
  if (!self.topViewSnapshot.superview && !self.shouldAllowUserInteractionsWhenAnchored) {
    topViewSnapshot.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageWithUIView:self.topView].CGImage;
    [self.topView addSubview:self.topViewSnapshot];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Unheilig for answering but this method is available in old ECSlidingViewController in new ECSlidingViewController it is not available

Comment: @PareshVasoya I am not the answerer :-) But thanks for the thought.

Comment: @Unheilig do you know how to accomplish this